# Xamarin Forms: IO.Directory.CreateDirectory doesn't support Chinese?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm developing a xamarin forms APP, in which I want to create a directory contains Chinese characters, like this:

```
var documentsPath = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path, "HEBTrain/Documents");
var path = Path.Combine(documentsPath, "1工段/课件");
Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
```

However, only "1工段" was created. 
All the source code is in an UTF-8 file, so it should not be related to encoding.
If I change the Chinese string "1工段/课件" to "1Dept/course_ware", then all the directories are created successfully.

Is there any bug in Directory.CreateDirectory?
Why is it not same with the .NET version?

Comment: I would file a bug - bugzilla.xamarin.com

Comment: @Jason Thank you for the comment. BTW, I also asked this question to android@xamarin.com, because I have purchased the Xamarin Business license, and I thought it should the fastest way to get a answer. But 20 days passed, I didn't receive any replies:(